# Laplace transform of bounded variation function extends to entire function. Does it imply the integral of the LT is absolutely convergent

Tags: laplace-transform

I have the following problem. Assume that $u$ is locally of bounded variation function on $(0,\infty)$ and can be of the form $u(y)=\bar{\mu}(y)-e^{-y}, y>0,$ where $\bar{\mu}(y)=\int_{y}^\infty\mu(du)$ with $\int_{0}^\infty\min\{u,1\}\mu(du)<\infty$. We know that
$$h(z)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-zy}u(y)dy$$
is absolutely convergent for $\Re(z)>-1$ and $h$ can be extended to an entire function. Does this imply that $e^{-zy}u(y)$ is absolutely integrable on $[0,\infty)$ for every complex number z?

I would appreciate any hint and perhaps some reference to a body of literature on Laplace transforms of signed measure provided you are aware of such.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ??? You say you know the integral is absolutely convergent on a certain set and then ask whether the integrand is absolutely integrable on a subset. What's the difference between "the integral coverges absolutely" and "the integrand is absolutely integrable"?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich If I understand correctly, the intended question is "Does this imply that for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$ the function $y \mapsto e^{-zy}u(y)$ is absolutely integrable on $[0,+\infty)$?".

Comment: Your question has many problems. $F(y)=\int_0^\infty e^{-zy} f(y)dy$ is entire if $f$ decreases faster than any exponential, or if one of its primitive does (for example $e^y\sin(e^{y^2})$). This condition is not necessary but it is the one that is easily checked. With $f(y)=\sum_{n\ge 1}(-1)^n \delta(y-\log n)$ then $F$ is entire but the Laplace transform integral diverges for $\Re(z)\le 0$.

Comment: Dear both, sorry for the sloppy comment. I will be more careful next time. Hopefully, I will get accustomed soon to the platform.  Indeed the correct question is: Does the fact that h is continued to entire function imply that $e^{-zy} u(y)$ is absolutely intégrable for every complex number z. 

Thanks for the counterexample. 

Best